# Trigger $digest from external code

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an application that exposes an methods (from various angular services) to code that is loaded and eval'd at runtime. What is the best way to guarantee $digest triggers when these methods are called from outside angular, taking into account that they might also be called from within angular? Should I expose a separate interface wrapped in $scope.$apply instead of exposing the service methods directly?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

call $timeout() function with no time.

for example

```
function someEventOutsideAngualer(value) {

  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.bindedValue = value;
  })
}
```

The idea is that when $timeout callback is executed, in our case it will be picked up with the next $digest. Please do not use $scope.$apply() and $digest triggers. They cause more problems than they solve, if not properly understood

Comment: Is there no built-in way to hook up to a currently running $digest instead of deferring to the next with $timeout? Without using private variables like $$phase of course.

Comment: No, the only clean way i know is calling $timeout, and allowing the next digest cycle, to apply your changes inside the $timeout callback.

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution would be to call $evalAsync. From documentation:

" if this function is called outside of a $digest cycle, a new $digest cycle will be scheduled. " https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

My advice to expose something outside Angular is to expose element (by providing ID or selector) where you have scope or (better) controller attached and then use 'angular.element(someDomEkenent).scope().someFunction()'

In this case you would avoid possibility to capture unessesary objects that can lead to memory leaks that is very hard to debug